# What is the most efficient way of retrieving the port value from this json list

Tags: python, json

I have the below list from which I have to retrieve the `port` number I want the value `50051` but what I get is `port=50051` I know I can retrieve this by iterating the list and using string operations but wanted to see if there is some direct way to access this.

```
r = requests.get(url_service)

data = {}
data = r.json()

#Below is the json after printing
[{'ServerTag': [  'abc-service=true',
                  'port=50051',
                  'protocol=http']
}]

print(data[0]["ServiceTags"][1]) // prints port=50051
```

Comment: This is not JSON which would use double quotes.

Comment: @LutzHorn this is how I am getting the data from server when I do a `GET` query

Comment: Fine. But it is still not JSON. Please [edit] your question, include the code you have tried, remove the JSON tag.

Comment: I'm confused. List literals don't have colons in them. Dict literals do, but they also require curly brackets, which you don't have. What is the exact type of your object?

Comment: @Kevin I have updated the question

Comment: to cut this short: no, there isn't. fetch the string containing 'port' from the list and then do a `split("=")[1]` on it.

Comment: Thanks @joppich that is what I wanted

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this perhaps:

```
received_dic = {
    'ServerTag': [  'abc-service=true',
                  'port=50051',
                  'protocol=http']
}

ServerTag = received_dic.get("ServerTag", None)
if ServerTag:
    port = list(filter(lambda x: "port" in x, ServerTag))[0].split("=")[1]
    print(port)   
# 50051
```

Comment: I would prefer not to call `exec` on an untrusted string I just got from a server I don't control...

Comment: Ok, I retract my objection :-)

Answer (score 0):

Considering you have the following JSON:

```
[
    {
         "ServerTag": ["abc-service=true", "port=50051", "protocol=http"]
    }
]
```

You can extract your value like this:

```
from functools import partial

# ...

def extract_value_from_tag(tags, name, default=None):
    tags = map(partial(str.split, sep='='), tags)
    try:
        return next(value for key, value in tags if key == name)
    except StopIteration:
        # Tag was not found
        return default
```

And then you just:

```
# Providing data is the deserialized JSON as a Python list
# Also assuming that data is not empty and ServerTag is present on the first object
tags = data[0].get('ServerTag', [])
port_number = extract_value_from_tag(tags, 'port', default='8080')
```